# write list columnwise in csv file using python

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [3,5,6]
list3 = [4,5,6]
```

I want output in csv file as:

```
A B C 
1 3 4
2 5 5
3 6 6
```

I tried using pandas as well as `np.savetxt()` but it doesnt work!

Answer (score 6):

Use `DataFrame` contructor with [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': list1, 'B': list2, 'C':list3}).to_csv('file.csv', index=False)
```

If want custom order of columns:

```
(pd.DataFrame({'A': list1, 'B': list2, 'C':list3}, columns=['B','A','C'])
   .to_csv('file.csv', index=False))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if you do not want to use external libraries:

```
import csv
with open('foo.csv', "wb") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(['A', 'B', 'C'])
        for i in range(0, len(list1)):
            writer.writerow([list1[i],list2[i],list3[i]])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
np.savetxt('test.csv', np.c_[l1,l2,l3], delimiter=' ', header='A B C',fmt='%d',comments='')
```