# Splitting a Dictonary and saving it into multiple CSV's

Tags: python, list, csv, split

I am trying to split my list of dict into multiple csv's but it's not working here is my code for this:

```
fruits = [ ##items 
    {"item": "apple",
        "quantity": 5,
        "price": 0.95},
    {
        "item": "orange",
        "quantity": 7,
        "price": 0.99
    },
    {
        "item": "orange",
        "quantity": 7,
        "price": 0.99
    },
    {
        "item": "orange",
        "quantity": 7,
        "price": 0.99
    },
    {
        "item": "orange",
        "quantity": 7,
        "price": 0.99
    }]
```

This is my list and here the code to the splitting

```
keys = fruits[0].keys()

try:
   os.mkdir("./CSV")
except OSError as e:
   print("Directory exists")

index = 0
for key in fruits:
    index += 1
    if index == 4:
        file_name = f"batch{x}.csv"
        with open("./CSV/" + f"batch{x}.csv", 'w', newline='') as output_file:
            dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
            dict_writer.writeheader()
            dict_writer.writerows(fruits)
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you want each dictionary in the list to be a separate csv file or is there some condition?

Comment: Your list of dicts contains syntax errors. But what do you want the individual csv files to contain?

Comment: yeah i would like to split every Dictionary into a csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I understand from your question is that you want each dictionary content to be written in a separate CSV file. here is a code that does that:

```
import sys
import os
import csv
fruits = [ ##items 
    {"item": "apple",
        "quantity": 5,
        "price": 0.95},
    {
        "item": "orange",
        "quantity": 7,
        "price": 0.99
    },
    {
        "item": "orange",
        "quantity": 7,
        "price": 0.99
    },
    {
        "item": "orange",
        "quantity": 7,
        "price": 0.99
    },
    {
        "item": "orange",
        "quantity": 7,
        "price": 0.99
    }]

keys = fruits[0].keys()

try:
   os.mkdir("./CSV")
except OSError as e:
   print("Directory exists")

index = 0
for dict_ in fruits:
   index +=1
   for k,v in dict_.items():
      #print(dict_)
      file_name = f"batch{index}.csv"
      with open("./CSV/" + f"batch{index}.csv", 'a', newline='') as output_file:
            dict_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
            dict_writer.writerow([k,v])
```

Output: 5 different CSV files batch1.csv, batch2.csv,..., batch5.csv, and each contain the content of the dictionary at the respective position in the fruits list.

Comment: And do you know how to split it after the 4th dict, so that i have a csv of the first 4 dicts and another one with only the 5th dict?

Comment: I didn't quite get what are you asking, the 4th and 5th dictionaries already have separate CSV files assigned to them, so do all other dictionaries.

Comment: Let's say I have a list with 50 dictonaries. my idea would be to create a csv after every fifth dict that has 5 dict each.

Comment: for that , add a count variable with the index variable, for every iteration of outer for loop, do count+=1, if count==5: count=0 , index+=1 (remove the current index+=1), that way you will change the index every five iteration, here changing the index is like changing to the next csv file.

Comment: Yeah thanks it's working, the only problem is that the column names are not like it should be. So it's not "item, quality and price" it's "item and apple"

Comment: If you want to do it like one heading row and data rows like table format, then you will need to make a 2D list that will contain 5 rows as lists, and append each row till you update the index, in that if statement, before updating index, write each item of the list with append mode writerow() and you will get that. alternatively , write the csv files column wise instead of row wise , for that refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794808/write-list-columnwise-in-csv-file-using-python

Comment: How would the first approach look like, or Is there not a easier way to do it automatically, because my list consist of 50 dictionaries?

Comment: Now that I think of it, you can try iterating the loop on dict.values(), that will only return the values of a dictionary and you may write the list obtained directly as a row in the file, I will suggest initiating the new CSV file by entering the heading row (when you do index+=1 i.e. new page , writerow the row["Items","Quantity","Prise"])as all the dictionaries have same format.

Comment: How do you mean to write the row, with a function or how do you mean that?

Comment: Here is my code: 

count = 0
index = 0
for dict_ in fruits:
    count +=1
    if count == 4:
        count=0
        index +=1
        dict_.writerow(['item', 'quantity', 'price'])
        for k,v in dict_.vals():
      
          file_name = f"batch{index}.csv"
          with open("./CSV/" + f"batch{index}.csv", 'w', newline='') as output_file:
                dict1 = csv.writer(output_file)
                dict1.writerow([k,v])

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your code to open the file first, write the header, then write the rows in a loop. What you have is writing the header before each row.

Comment: Yeah but i would like to split it into multiple csvs files after the 4th key based on my list, and I do not know which file to open then.

Comment: Then build multiple dictionaries, one for each file.